# How to store the data given to a function on standard input?

Tags: shell, pipe, function, input

```
> cat b.txt 
function first
    {
    foo=$(SOMEMAGIC)
    }

echo nyi | first 
>
```

**Question**: How can we give the "nyi" string to the "foo" variable inside the function? So how can we give the data that was given to the function via pipeline to a variable inside the function?

Answer (score 5):

You can do one of these

### Read one line of standard input

```
function first
{
    IFS="" read -r foo
}

echo nyi | first
```

or

### Read the first argument

```
function first
{
    foo="$1"
}

first nyi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cat` to consume the input and then return it into the assignment.

```
$ first () { foo=$(cat); echo b${foo}c; }
$ echo nyi | first
bnyic
```